# after update to 6.3.3 I get in pipe() error TS2557: Expected at least 0 arguments, but got 1 or more.

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs6

Please someone can help,

in rxjs 6.3.3 pipe get TS2557: Expected at least 0 arguments, but got 1 or more.

```
   let currentPath;
const pipeArguments = path
  .map((subPath: string, index: number) => [
    flatMap((href: string) => {
      console.log('href', href);
      return this.getEndpointMapAt(href);
    }),
    map((endpointMap: EndpointMap) => {
      console.log('map', endpointMap);
      if (hasValue(endpointMap) && hasValue(endpointMap[subPath])) {
        currentPath = endpointMap[subPath];
        return endpointMap[subPath];
      } else {
        currentPath += '/' + subPath;
        return currentPath;
      }
    })
  ])
  .reduce((combined, thisElement) => [...combined, ...thisElement], []);
return of(this.getRootHref()).pipe(
  ...pipeArguments,
  distinctUntilChanged()
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until the code linked to that issue is merged, I think you're stuck with the same as any hack seen here, so: [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/12357/files#diff-e2ed7d40edb832433e17c58f41ac6539)

and [issue](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/4279)

```
return (of('http://localhost:8001/1/') as any).pipe(
 ...pipeArguments,
 distinctUntilChanged()
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem with static typing. Casting to `any` works, but it's a hack.

A type-safe approach is to `reduce()` over the pipe array:

```
return pipeArguments
    .reduce((obs, op) => obs.pipe(op), of('http://localhost:8001/1/'))
    .pipe(distinctUntilChanged()
```

Reference:

- https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3989
- https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/4177